# Decode C structure Datagram packet in java through UDP

Tags: java, android, c, udp

**Here is my java code for Android app:**

```
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.x.xxx");
int port = xxx;
DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length, address, port);
DatagramSocket ds = new DatagramSocket(port);
ds.receive(p);
Log.d("..........","Packet Received");
Log.d("UDP", "Received: '" + new String(p.getData()).trim() + "'");
```

I am able to receive packets but I am not able to decode in correct manner. On other side I am sending packet in structure (C program). I do not have right to change server code, so I need to decode that server structure packet into java object ?? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How do you define "correct manner"?

Comment: You cant change server but you should have access to packet format, show us. Also print packet data as text is wrong, just use HEX.

Comment: Correct manner in the sense , want to print the data which i receive from the C structure , If i use string like above to code it printing some binay/understandable format in java ...

Comment: @JIV Here is my C structure <br/> typedef  struct 
{
  char            frameType;
  char                  frameInfo;
  unsigned short    duration;
  unsigned char         address1[6];
  unsigned char        address2[6];        
  unsigned char         address3[6];      
  unsigned short        seqCtrl;
  unsigned short      qosControl;

}MacHeader; <br/><br/> An d am sending like this, <br/> sendto(sockfd,&cmdReq,pktlen,0,(struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));

Comment: So you have all byte-counts. Read the byte[] into a ByteBuffer and then have it spit out the appropriate types. For example: char for char, unsigned short - probably int, char[] to char[] or String and so on.

Comment: @Fildor yes i have all byte counts ... AM new to this, Can you explain me with some sample code for above C structure ... please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the `byte[]` you get from `p.getData()` using [ByteBuffer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#wrap%28byte%5B%5D%29).
Then use ByteBuffer's getXXX Methods to retrieve the according values.

Example for the first `char` "frameType" you'd go like this:

```
char frameType = (char) myByteBuffer.get(); // getChar() would fetch 2 bytes !!
```

See ByteBuffer doc for further info.

Comment: int val = bytes[1] << 8 | bytes[2];     Solved my problem.Thanks.